# Is it acceptable for a WordPress theme to not accept widgets?

Tags: theme-development, themes, widgets

I'm developing my own WordPress theme, and I was going through the [Theme Unit Test](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Unit_Test) as described by the Wordpress Codex. Now, at some point, the Codex mentions that I should verify that

> All widgets display correctly

Now, on the other hand, I have seen in the [Widget help page](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Widgets) that is instructed for users to verify if their theme supports widgets at all.

So, **is it ok if my theme does not support widgets?**

My goal is to have it published at some point and available to users through the Wordpress.org site, but since the design is quite minimal, I had decided not to support widgets. Am I asking too much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on where you distribute the theme. If you want to place it on WordPress.org, it must allow and display widgets. If you release it via your own website, or some others possibly, widgets can be optional, though I would always recommend they be supported.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what pippin said, it is not just a matter of following rules but also being practical. If you don't have widget support then the users can't customize their site without coding, something that will make your theme very not appealing to users

Comment: And also a widget not necessarily have to *look like a widget*.